# Where to put action listeners?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm a little confused about where the best class is for `ActionListener` instances in a small Swing application.

If I have a `Controller`, a `MainFrame` for the main `JFrame` and various `JPanel` containers such as `LeftPanel`, `RightPanel` etc, each with buttons, a list etc.

Where's the best place to put the action listeners? Should I have them in the same class as the components (as an inner class or class implementing action listener), in the `MainFrame` as this is the 'parent' of all the panels, or in the `Controller`, which really only has the `main()` method and a few other Swing details?

Each approach seems to have its pros and cons. I am trying to un-couple features from functionality but I'm finding it hard to work this out.

Or have I missed another (better) way?

Comment: Use [Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instead. Easy to handle inside a class or as separate classes if you come up with a lot of them.

Comment: I use lambda for action listener.  See the example below:

Comment: Part of this problem starts when coders extend components and windows unnecessarily. I'd start by .. *not* doing that for any of the frames *or* panels in this app. As an aside *".. the main JFrame.."* - there should be only one. For the rest, dialogs or option panes are probably the best alternative.

Comment: Generally, I place `ActionListeners` inside their own class.  If a `JPanel` form has a lot of input `JTextFields`, I'll create a private inner class so I don't have to pass several `JTextField` instances to the `ActionListener`.  I don't usually have a single controller class.  Each `Action` or `Listener` updates its own portion of the model and the view.

Answer (score -1):

One possible for the panels to communicate with each other is through the main frame.  Each panel would have a reference to the main frame and the main frame provides all the operations such as reading data from the form, updating data to the form.  Below is an example:

```
class UserForm extends JPanel {
    private final MyApp app;
    private final JTextField userNameField = new JTextField(20);
    public UserForm(MyApp app){
        this.app = app;
        this.add(userNameField);
    }
    public String getUserName(){
        return userNameField.getText();
    }
    public void setUserName(String name){
        userNameField.setText(name);
    }
}
class FormControl extends JPanel {
    private final MyApp app;
    private final JButton randNameButton = new JButton("Random");
    private final JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    private final String[] names = {"john", "mike", "bill", "joe"};
    private final Random r = new Random();
    public FormControl(MyApp app){
        this.app = app;
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(randNameButton);
        this.add(saveButton);
        randNameButton.addActionListener(e->app.setUserName(names[r.nextInt(4)]));
        saveButton.addActionListener(e->app.save());
    }
}
public class MyApp extends JFrame{
    private final UserForm form = new UserForm(this);
    private final FormControl control = new FormControl(this);
    public MyApp(){
        this.setTitle("Demo");
        this.setSize(200, 100);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setSize(200,100);
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pane.add(form, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pane.add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setContentPane(pane);
    }
    
    // all the operations are here.
    public String getUserName(){
        return form.getUserName();
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName){
        form.setUserName(userName);
    }
    public void save(){
        System.out.println("Saving");
        System.out.println(getUserName());
        System.out.println("Done saving.");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyApp().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: still not good, f.i. don't extend classes when you can reach the same with configuration, don't introduce extensive/unneeded coupling, do  create and show a swing app on the EDT, do separate data and view, ...

Comment: In that case, why not use the lookup design pattern used in NetBeans platform?  Components are not aware of the existence of other components but only that they implement a specific interface and register themselves.

Answer (score -2):

I would use lambda for action listener.  See example below:

```
public class JavaApplication7 extends JFrame{
    public JavaApplication7(){
        this.setTitle("Demo");
        this.setSize(100, 100);
        JButton b = new JButton("Click");
        b.addActionListener(e->{
            System.out.println("hello");
            System.out.println("from " + this.getTitle());
        });
        this.setContentPane(b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication7().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) That's terrible code. If it was in a question I might be willing to offer tips, but as an answer it should be deleted (or extensively changed). 2) I don't see how it answers the question. The OP is not asking *how* to make an action listener, they are asking *where* to create them.

Comment: There are many ways to create action listeners.  And I just showed one.  The lambda expression is the action listener (short hand for an antonymous class).  I could list a bunch of others ways but this is the simplest of them.

Comment: Using Action just seems to create the same problem in a different way. I want, for example, a button in LeftPanel.class to update text in a textArea in RightPanel.class but if I create a reference to RightPanel.class in LeftPanel.class, which seems to be the only way to do it, I'm back to them being tightly coupled. I feel I'm missing something that allows two JPanels in the same JFrame to communicate effectively.

Comment: _button in LeftPanel.class to update text in a textArea in RightPanel.class_ wrong approach - you _should not_ extend view (or any other) classes when you can achieve the same by configuration, you _should not_ let separate views talk to each other, they should not even know each other (all should talk/listen to the model).

Comment: Thanks @ChengThao. That makes sense to me. I wasn't sure about passing a reference from the frame to each panel. I know there's no inheritance here, but that felt like passing some 'down' which didn't feel quite right.

Comment: @Roger It's a common practice to pass the parent to the children.  For example, each node is a tree has a reference to its parent.  So that a node can be asked for its parents and the parent's parents.  There's nothing weird about it.  It's just an approach you take.  Whatever approach, you will always need a reference to the object you want to manipulate whether that's done through passing the reference via the constructor, a set method, or some dependency injection mechanism.